# R Can Not Be Resolved To A Variable Slide Menu + Sherlock

Tags: android, android-activity, actionbarsherlock, android-menu, r.java-file

I am trying to use Slide Menu + Action Sherlock, but I am still getting this annoying error.

I have followed the steps by importing Slide Menu, setting it as a library and create a dependency on the project. I have done the same for Action Sherlock by creating a dependency on the library. I have also changed the libs directory, so they all had android-support-v4.

Then I have changed the project build target to Google API 19 for every project, since the slide menu and ASB had API level 17 in their manifest, I have changed it to 19.

I have also cleaned the projects several times.

My Main Activity is now extending "SlidingFragmentActivity" (Slide Menu), which is then extending SherlockFragmentActivity and implementing SlidingActivityBase.

If I try to import with CMD + SHIFT + O on the MainActivity, import android.R; gets imported and creates more errors. I have read on other threads that this shouldn't be imported, so I have removed it.

Nothing has changed.

ps: I have set the minimum SDK to 11 for SlideMenu, Sherlock and my project.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the problem with sliding menu/ sherlock,

Try `Project->clean` your project, or delete R.java from gen folder & restart eclipse !

And for the errors in xml :

In your project.properties, change target=android-x where x < 11 to some x >= 11 e.g target=android-14, because holo was introduced first in android-11 (Honeycomb). Also, x>=14 for android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar to work.

Hope it helps

Comment: I have just realised that in Gen there is just a BuildConfig.java and not a R.java, could that be the problem? : \

Comment: Restarting the eclipse will generate `R.java` because at that time all the projects in workspace will build freshly & R.java will be updated

Comment: I have restarted and my project still doesn't have the R.java

Comment: Try switching the workspace, make the new project, & copy all the things within that

Comment: By looking at the console, I have found several different errors here: /WorkSpace/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml. There are like 50 attributes that have already been "defined", but I haven't defined anything, so I don't see where the conflict is.

Comment: Try Right click on your` project -> Close Unrelated Projects`

Comment: This is the result of that in the console: [2014-06-28 14:03:47 - Exampe] Unknown error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: The main problem is that ActionSherlock is conflicting with AppCompact, which I have now removed; but by removing AppCompact, I get other errors in style.xml, because they can't find the "Theme.AppCompat.Light".

Comment: Now,Do you fix `R Can Not Be Resolved To A Variable ` problem ?

Comment: Nope, because the R.java can't be generated since I still have those errors in style.xml.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in my post, I am targeting min 11 and max 19. I wonder if Holo is implemented in AppCompact, which I have removed as a library.